# Adding a random member from an array of chars to a game board in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I am programming a game for a university project and i am having a little trouble with it. So here is my game board class header file:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <time.h>

class CMagicAlchemistBoard
{
public:

CMagicAlchemistBoard(void); //  Default Constructor
CMagicAlchemistBoard(const CMagicAlchemistBoard& board); //  Copy Constructor 
~CMagicAlchemistBoard(void ); //  Destructor
void SetupBoard(void);  // Function to setup the board
int GetBoardSpace(int row, int col); // Get the color at row,col

//  Accessor functions to get/set board size information 
int GetColumns(void) const { return m_nColumns; }
void SetColumns(int nColumns)  { m_nColumns = (nColumns >= 6) ? nColumns : 6; }
int GetRows(void) const { return m_nRows; }
void SetRows(int nRows)  { m_nRows = (nRows >= 8) ? nRows : 8; }

void DeleteBoard(void); //  Function to delete the board and free memory
void ExecuteMove(int row, int col);
bool IsGameOver(void) const;  //  Is the game over?
void DrawBoard(void);
bool ValidMove(int row, int col); // Function to see if a move is valid
char RandomPiece();

private:

void CreateBoard(void); //Function to create the board and allocate memory
// Class Data
int** m_arrBoard; // 2D array pointer
//  Board size information
char m_arrChars[20];
int m_nColumns;
int m_nRows;


   };
```

And here are the important parts of the game board .cpp file:

```
#include "cmagicalchemistboard.h"
using namespace std;

CMagicAlchemistBoard::CMagicAlchemistBoard(void)
: m_arrBoard(NULL), m_nColumns(6), m_nRows(8)

{ 
m_arrChars[0] = ' ';
}   

CMagicAlchemistBoard::CMagicAlchemistBoard(const CMagicAlchemistBoard& board)
{
  //  Copy all of the regular data members
m_nColumns = board.m_nColumns; m_nRows = board.m_nRows;
m_arrBoard = NULL;
CreateBoard();  //  Create a new game board of the same size
//  Copy the contents of the game board
for(int row = 0; row < m_nRows; row++)
for(int col = 0; col < m_nColumns; col++)
  m_arrBoard[row][col] = board.m_arrBoard[row][col];
int CMagicAlchemistBoard::GetBoardSpace(int row, int col)
{
if(row<0 || row>=m_nRows || col<0 || col>=m_nColumns) return 0;
return m_arrBoard[row][col];
}

void CMagicAlchemistBoard::CreateBoard(void)
{
  //  If there is already a board, delete it
if(m_arrBoard != NULL) DeleteBoard();
//  Create the array of rows
m_arrBoard = new int*[m_nRows];
//  Create each row
for(int row = 0; row < m_nRows; row++){
m_arrBoard[row] = new int[m_nColumns];
//  Set each square to be empty
for(int col = 0; col < m_nColumns; col++)
  m_arrBoard[row][col] = 0;
}
```

}

```
void CMagicAlchemistBoard::DrawBoard(void)
{

cout << "MAGIC ALCHEMIST" << endl;
cout << "  ";
for(int col = 0; col < m_nColumns; col++){ printf(" ---",col); }
cout << endl;
for(int row = 0; row < m_nRows; row++)
{
    for(int col = 0; col < m_nColumns; col++)
    {

 //     printf("| %c", m_arrChars[0]);
        cout << "|  " << m_arrChars[0];
    }
    cout << "| " << endl; 
 }
}
```

So my idea is to have a function that will add one random char between 12 chars to m_arrBoard[0][2] position. Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: If you are looking for somebody to review your code, http://codereview.stackexchange.com is the right place to go. If you are running into problems, tell what those problems are and somebody might be able to help.

Comment: my problem is that i want to write a function that i dont know how to write.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that returns a random character out of 12 predefined
characmters. Call it to assign a random character to `m_arrBoard[0][2]`.

```
// The function to get a random character.
char getRandomChar()
{
    char arr[12] = {}; // Initialize the array of characters.
    int index = rand()%12;
    return arr[index];
}
```

Somewhere down in some function....

```
// Assign a random character to m_arrBoard[0][2].
m_arrBoard[0][2] = getRandomChar();
```

Comment: can i assign it to m_arrBoard[][] on the same function?

Comment: @user3674599 of course you can. but keeping them separate keeps your code clean. The function `getRandomChar()` just returns a random character. It doesn't matter how it's used. The calling functions decide where to use them. Think of separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to receive random characters from A to Z. You can try the following code:

```
std::vector<char> arr;
int n = (90-65 +1);//'Z'-'A'
int movePosition = 65;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
{
    int number = rand() % n;//Get a number from 0 to n-1 (where n is 26)
    std::cout << "number = " << number << "; movePosition = " << movePosition << std::endl;

    // To get a letter add movePosition to it so you are back in the range of 65 to 90
    arr.push_back((char)(number + movePosition));
}
```

To see what characters you have added, you can try the following:

```
for (int i = 0;i<arr.size();i++)
{
    std::cout << "Char=" << arr[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `seed = (90-65)` sets it to 25 - you'll need to add one if you ever want to get a 'Z'.  Given the use of `seed` ala `rand() % seed` - your "seed" is misleadingly named... in the context of random numbers, a seed is the value used to initialise the pseudo random number generator, often in such a way that each seed then yields a distinct sequence repeating after a known period, and if you re-seed the PRNG with the same seed you'll restart the same sequence.